# Matlab: Calling a function of a .m file from another .m file

Tags: matlab

I have two files in the same directory. Say `FolderX/A.m` and `FolderX/B.m`.
In `A.m`, I have a function defined as 
`function [Out] = fun(AA, Cal)`

I tried appending the global keyword before the function but that throws `syntax error`

```
function [Out] = fun(AA, Cal)
```

Comment: Read here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for you to call a function from another m file is if that function is defined as its own m-file (fun.m) or if you copy and paste the fun definition to B.m

Addressing your previous comment, it sounds like you had a script file that calls a function, and that function is defined within the script. To follow the advice given by that answer, you would have to make a separate m-file that only contains the function definition

Comment: Thanks creating a new file worked. Still wondering why there was a need to create a separate file?

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, the `global` keyword applies only to variables.

If you want a function or script in `FolderX` to be accessible from other functions or scripts, just ensure that `FolderX` is in Matlab's path. This can be done either by being on this folder or with `addpath`.

Note that your functions should have the same name as the file name. And you should avoid having scripts and function files with the same name within Matlab's path.

Hence file `A.m` should declare the function as:

`function [Out] = A(AA, Cal)`

While file `B.m` should do it as:

`function [Out] = B(AA, Cal)`

but preferably use better names than `A` and `B`.

Comment: Tried that and now it shows "Unable to define local function because it has the same name as the file."

Comment: Yep, this helps. I cannot mark two answers as correct so my apologies. Both the answers helped. Thank you!